# What happens when a case-insensitive client contacts and webserver?

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems

I've just got to know that some filesystems, such as FAT, store filenames as upper-case regardless of the case used to create them. So it's not possible to have Bishop.png and bishop.png in the same folder, is it?

What happens if I have a Linux server with those two files in one folder and I create a webpage like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="Bishop.png" />
        <img src="bishop.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Now this page get requested by a Windows 98 client (I think they had only FAT).
Will Bishop.png be displayed twice? Will bishop.png be displayed twice? Or will both images be displayed although Windows 98 couldn't distinguish these files if they were stored locally?

(I don't have any possibility to check this for myself as I only have Linux)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filesystem used by the client should not matter. It will just send a request to the server using the exact capitalization it finds in the HTML page, since the path part of URLs is case-sensitive by definition. If later it wants to cache the image locally, it has greater problems than letter case, such as not confusing bishop.png's from two different sites with each other. Solving those problems will in general entail a solution to letter case too, even if the local filesystem cannot do it by itself.

Comment: Do you have a Windows 98 machine with IE 6 or older? I would like to try it. If anyone has a Win98 and IE6-, here is the webpage: http://www.martin-thoma.de/case-sensitivity/

Comment: Besides, the browser cannot assume that the url contains a valid filename in any form. For example, you may configure your webserver to use URLs with GET parameters like `<img src="img?foo=c:\*"/><img src="img?foo=|>"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Pumaa80. I knew that, but I didn't have it in mind as I asked. Also I don't know if this configuration was possible with old servers (old software).